# how to make sure that JButtons are being pressed in ascending order based on their text

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-interface

My question is how would I use a loop in the buttonHandler() to be able to determine if the button pressed had a value greater than the one before. So what i'm looking for is a way to make sure that whomever is clicking the buttons is clicking them in ascending order based on the number they see. It is a GUI game based on clicking buttons in ascending order to assess dexterity.

Here is the method in which button array is filled with numbers from 1-12, this also makes sure that there are no duplicate numbers so it will have all the numbers from 1-12 regardless.

```
public static JButton[] randNum ()
    {

        arrayImage [0] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        arrayImage [1] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [1] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [1] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [2] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [2] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [2] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [2] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [3] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [3] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [3] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [3] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [3] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [4] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [4] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [4] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [4] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [4] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [4] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [5] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [5] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [5] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [5] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [5] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [5] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [5] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [6] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [6] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [6] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [7] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [6] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [7] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [7] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [8] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [7] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [6] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [8] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [8] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [9] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [8] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [7] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [6] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [9] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [9] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [10] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [9] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [8] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [7] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [6] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [10] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [10] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }
        arrayImage [11] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        while (arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [10] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [9] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [8] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [7] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [6] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [5] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [4] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [3] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [2] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [1] || arrayImage [11] == arrayImage [0])
        {
            arrayImage [11] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
        }

        for (int x = 0 ; x <= 11 ; x++)
        {
            buttonArray [x] = new JButton ("" + arrayImage [x]);
            buttonArray [x].setBackground (Color.orange);
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 11 ; i++)
        {
            buttonArray [i].setActionCommand ("" + arrayImage [i]);

        }

        return buttonArray;
    }
```

This is the way I introduced the button array in the main method.

```
static JButton btnStart, buttonArray[] = new JButton [12];
```

Giving them color, and a loop used to give them each action listeners sequentially.

```
for (int x = 0 ; x <= 11 ; x++)
        {
            buttonArray [x] = new JButton ("");
            buttonArray [x].setBackground (Color.orange);
        }


        ButtonHandler onClick = new ButtonHandler ();
        btnStart.addActionListener (onClick);
        for (int y = 0 ; y <= 11 ; y++)
        {
            buttonArray [y].addActionListener (onClick);
        }
```

And here is the introduction of the panels, and adding the components to the panels. Then adding the panels to the frame..

```
JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel (new GridLayout (2, 6));
        gameBoard.setBackground (Color.orange);
        JPanel gameContent = new JPanel (new GridLayout (1, 2));
        JPanel mainGame = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());



         //GAme Board
        gameContent.add (btnStart);
        gameContent.add (scoreOutput);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [0]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [1]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [2]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [3]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [4]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [5]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [6]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [7]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [8]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [9]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [10]);
        gameBoard.add (buttonArray [11]);


        mainGame.add (gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainGame.add (gameContent, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



Container contentPane1 = questions.getContentPane ();
        contentPane1.add (mainGame);


questions.setSize (500, 250);
        questions.setVisible (true);
```

Comment: You can use one string .When u first press a button. Add button number in string .Now when next button is pressed you check the last number that is pressed and current button's number and if it is greater than previous then it's fine if not than you can show error . You can also use integer array to store presses button's values and check for ur condition . Answer is given hoping that you have adequate knowledge of how to get single character from string and how to convert it into integer.

Comment: is that the toString() command?

Comment: But if buttons are more than 10 then you must use array to store it's number and using array.length-1 you can get the last index of array in which number is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you must have to give numbers as their name to buttons .
You can do like this :
Take one array and one variable:

```
int pressed[] = new int[12];
int n;
```

Set value of n to 0 in constructor. 
Now in actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) method :

```
if(pressed.length==0)
    pressed[n]=Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand());

else 
    Check if last number in array is less than current number
    else show error
```

You can get last number using:
    pressed[pressed.length-1]